# Node.js exec fails on window command

Tags: node.js, windows, command, command-line-interface

I have the following code I am executing in node.js to capture drive letters.

```
        let cmd = 'echo off && for %i in ( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ) do %i: 2>nul && set/pz=%i <nul';
    var drive,drives;
    try { // this command throws an exception but stdout is still available.
        drives = await exec(cmd);
    }
    catch(e){
        drives=e.stdout;
    };
```

The exec always fails and the catch returns the correct answer in e.stdout.   My workaround is to just let it fail and get the answer from the catch.

However, I hate this approach and was wondering if someone knew a way to exec this windows command without causing triggering the catch.